# Deploying failed in AWS Elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a problem in deploying PHP based web application in AWS EB.  I tried to push files using GIT bash; it went fine and shows completed 100%.

Then I checked in my AWS console it shows "**Environment update is starting**." after few seconds it shows 
"Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Stack:arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:556003586595:stack/awseb-e-m3tbtwpcpe-stack/0bb57070-5fac-11e2-af2e-5081b23f0c86 is in **UPDATE_ROLLBACK_FAILED state and can not be updated**."

"**Failed to deploy application**."

Please help someone how to resolve this issue.  I am in urgency of setting the web application in AWS EB as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance,
Sankar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried rebuilding the environment from the [AWS Console](http://console.aws.amazon.com)? Are you doing anything less common like running your Beanstalk environment inside of a VPC?

Comment: Yes; I tried in AWS console to deploy the build, there also I am getting the same error.
Sorry I am not aware of VPC.  Whats that VPC ?

Comment: No, not _deploy_ — _rebuild the environment_.

Comment: And if you don't know what VPC is, then I suppose the answer is no. :) But for future reference: [Amazon VPC](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/).

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I rebuilt the environment and its working fine now.

Comment: It didn't work for me even after rebuilding the environment.

Comment: Rebuilding the environment fixed a long-standing issue I had.  Thanks for the tip, I never even noticed that option.